# NHibernate executing a SELECT before every INSERT

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have an entity with only one field (`Value`) and the following mapping:

```
Id(x => x.Value).Column("value").Length(150);
```

When I execute the following code

```
using (var tx = Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var e = new Entity { Id = "Value" + i };
        Database.Entities.Add(e);
    }
    tx.Commit();
}
```

NHibernate executes a `SELECT` statement before each `INSERT` call. Something like this:

```
NHibernate: SELECT * FROM entity entity_ WHERE entity_.value=@p0; @p0 = 'Value0'
NHibernate: INSERT INTO entity ...
NHibernate: SELECT * FROM entity entity_ WHERE entity_.value=@p0; @p0 = 'Value1'
NHibernate: INSERT INTO entity ...
NHibernate: SELECT * FROM entity entity_ WHERE entity_.value=@p0; @p0 = 'Value2'
NHibernate: INSERT INTO entity ...
```

If I enable the bulk mode (setting `adonet.batch_size`) it executes all the `SELECT` statements first and then the `INSERT` ones in bulk mode.

Is that the intended behavior? If so, what should I do to avoid that?

Comment: creating Entity with Id will fetch it from database, so it's intended behaviour

Comment: What object type is "Database"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is correct, related to these facts:

1. The ID beeing string -> has generator type **assigned** (the fluent-mapping line in a question)
2. While discouraged, the `session.SaveOrUpdate(e)` was used

See: [5.1.4.7. Assigned Identifiers](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-id-assigned), Extract:

> Due to its inherent nature, entities that use this generator cannot be
>   saved via the ISession's SaveOrUpdate() method. Instead you have to
>   explicitly specify to NHibernate if the object should be saved or
>   updated by calling either the Save() or Update() method of the
>   ISession.

In this case, NHibernate is almost desperate. Why? Because there is no way how to assure, that the assigned id ('value1', 'value2'..) is already in DB or not. So, to be sure if the *INSERT* or *UPDATE* should be issued, it must ask the DB. That's why the SELECT before that decision.

Use the `Save(e)` only, behind the `Database.Entities.Add(e)` and no *supporting infrastructural* SELECT will be issued.

Comment: Thank you very much, Radim! It totally makes sense: If I call `SaveOrUpdate`, it needs to know if the entity exists first! I tried with `Save` and it works perfect ;)

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. Enjoy NHibernate... amazing tool ;)